# How can I eval code with inline source map in browser to get a proper stack in exception?

Tags: javascript

Here is a code with inlined source map:

```
let b = 'sws';\r\nlet f = 'zzz';\r\nconsole.log('wow');\r\nfunction ff() {\r\n    console.log('wwwww');\r\n    return 'WEEE'.tr();\r\n}\r\nconsole.log(ff());\r\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoidGVzdC5qcyIsInNvdXJjZVJvb3QiOiIiLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbInRlc3QudHMiXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUEsSUFBSSxDQUFDLEdBQUcsS0FBSyxDQUFDO0FBQ2QsSUFBSSxDQUFDLEdBQUcsS0FBSyxDQUFDO0FBQ2QsT0FBTyxDQUFDLEdBQUcsQ0FBQyxLQUFLLENBQUMsQ0FBQTtBQUVsQixTQUFTLEVBQUU7SUFDUCxPQUFPLENBQUMsR0FBRyxDQUFDLE9BQU8sQ0FBQyxDQUFBO0lBQ3BCLE9BQU8sTUFBTSxDQUFDLEVBQUUsRUFBRSxDQUFDO0FBQ3ZCLENBQUM7QUFDRCxPQUFPLENBQUMsR0FBRyxDQUFDLEVBQUUsRUFBRSxDQUFDLENBQUEifQ=="
```

if I simply do an eval for that code I'll get an exception but without an aligned source map. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`sourceMappingURL` [seems deprecated.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/06/sourceMappingURL-and-sourceURL-syntax-changed) Have you tried with `sourceURL` instead ?